# Rate the App in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store

I integrated rate app functionality as follow:

```
-(void)doRateApp {
    NSString *link = [@"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=" stringByAppendingString:@"xxxxxxx"];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:link]]; 
}
```

**Que: Is there any way to redirect with 5 star automatically to app store?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Of course not. Unfortunately we have to rely on the old way of getting 5 star rated apps: making great apps.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=star+rating

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to cheat apple it caught problem on your app.

star with title and comments through rate the app. so for don't waste your time for that. Just ask to user like app rate now or rate later or don't want etc.,

Note:

Don't try any third party framework or trying to access any other approach it may be rejected from apple. don't take risk

Answer (score 1):

You can trick as it does many successful apps. You can show popup to user which asked him: "Do you like this app? Rate it please" and also show on this popup 5 empty stars. If user tap on 5 - redirect to appstore. If 4 or less - redirect to email controller with problem reporting.
This method a little bit dirty, but it can significantly improve rate of your app.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to permit the user to choose the Rating and even if you find some hack it won't go beyond Appstore Review, they will reject it.